# No matching constructor for initialization of MyClassName

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, shared-ptr, move-semantics

I have a class, in the code snipped I pasted the parts of it where I think the problem is.

```
class SubtreeExplorer : public AbstractTask {
 public:
  SubtreeExplorer(Threadpool& tp, SudokuBoard&& sudoku)
      : tp(tp), sudoku(std::move(sudoku)) {}

 ...

 private:
  Threadpool& tp;
  SudokuBoard sudoku;
 
  bool sudoku_backtracking_search(SudokuBoard& s) {
   ...
   while(...){
      ...
      // let another thread explore the subtree
      tp.submit(make_shared<SubtreeExplorer>(tp, SudokuBoard(sudoku)));
   }
  }
};
```

When I try to compile it it gives the error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4325:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_constructible<SubtreeExplorer,
      Threadpool &, SudokuBoard &>::value' "Can't construct object in make_shared"
    static_assert( is_constructible<_Tp, _Args...>::value, "Can't construct object in make_shared" );
```

I'm using VS Code and in the IDE no errors are highlighted.
The problem is caused probably by the `make_shared`, but I can't figure out what is in the constructor ok the SubtreeExplorer class that causes it.

`Sudokuboard(sudoku)` returns a new board, from a given one, with few modifications. I want this new board to be moved inside the new subtree explorer.

Looking on google, the constructor I wrote should move the board inside, but still I get compile error I wrote, plus a long list of hard to read notes:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2259:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<SubtreeExplorer, 1, false>::__compressed_pair_elem<Threadpool &, SudokuBoard &, 0, 1>' requested here
        _Base2(__pc, _VSTD::move(__second_args),
        ^ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3672:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::allocator<SubtreeExplorer>, SubtreeExplorer>::__compressed_pair<std::__1::allocator<SubtreeExplorer> &,
      Threadpool &, SudokuBoard &>' requested here
            :  __data_(piecewise_construct, _VSTD::forward_as_tuple(__a),
               ^ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4331:26: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<SubtreeExplorer, std::__1::allocator<SubtreeExplorer>
>::__shared_ptr_emplace<Threadpool &, SudokuBoard &>' requested
      here
    ::new(__hold2.get()) _CntrlBlk(__a2, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                         ^ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4710:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::shared_ptr<SubtreeExplorer>::make_shared<Threadpool &, SudokuBoard &>' requested here
    return shared_ptr<_Tp>::make_shared(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                            ^ src/sudoku_parallel.cpp:119:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::make_shared<SubtreeExplorer, Threadpool &, SudokuBoard
      &>' requested here   tp.submit(make_shared<SubtreeExplorer>(tp, sudoku));
            ^ src/sudoku_parallel.cpp:41:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'SudokuBoard' to 'SudokuBoard &&' for 2nd argument   SubtreeExplorer(Threadpool& tp, SudokuBoard&& sudoku)   ^ src/sudoku_parallel.cpp:39:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided class SubtreeExplorer : public AbstractTask {
      ^ src/sudoku_parallel.cpp:39:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
```

that give me the idea I'm passing the wrong number of arguments to the constructor even though it takes two arguments and I pass the two arguments, a threadpool and a sudoku board.

In the main, the SubtreeExplorer is created like in the body of the sudoku_backtracking_search function:

```
int main() {
   ...
   SubokuBoard sudoku(filepath);
   tp.submit(make_shared<SubtreeExplorer>(tp, sudoku));
   ...
}
```

EDIT:
tp is a threadpool, whose submit method has this signature:

```
bool submit(std::shared_ptr<AbstractTask> task);
```

and the AbstractTask class is the following:

```
struct AbstractTask {
  virtual ~AbstractTask() = default;
  virtual void run() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Where is the code that uses the constructor? Please make a [mre]

Comment: @cigien it't the `tp.submit(make_shared<SubtreeExplorer>(tp, SudokuBoard(sudoku)));`

Comment: Oh, ok, but what is `submit`, etc? It'd be nice if we could simply copy the code you show, and reproduce the error.

Comment: @cigien I know but it's a code that's split into multiple files. So I'll have to paste all the headers and implementation files. I don't think it's doable. I'll edit and insert the signature of submit.

Comment: please post a [mre]. The error message appears to have no relation to the code you posted. You do not have to "paste all the headers and implementation files". Read about [mre] and try to create one

Comment: @idclev463035818 the error message has a relation with the construction of the subtree explorer class, whose constructor I put entirely, along with the two places where it's called.

Comment: the message refers to `: __value_(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(_VSTD::get<_Indexes>(__args))...) {}` which I cannot find in the code

Comment: @idclev463035818 a part was missing, I edited and put it the missing part. I'm now working on a minimal reproducible example I'll post when I'm finished. Thanks.

Comment: @idclev463035818 That's code from the standard library implementation.

Comment: In main you should do:  `std::move(sudoku)`, `SubtreeExplorer` takes rvalue reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor takes an rvalue reference to `SudokuBoard` but you pass it an lvalue.  This is why you get the error; an lvalue reference cannot be implicitly converted to an rvalue reference, and so the call fails.

You can correct the problem using any of these options:

1. The best option would be to change the `SubtreeExplorer` constructor to accept the second argument by value, which allows the caller to either move-construct or copy-construct it, depending on whether they need to retain a copy of the argument.  You get the benefit of move semantics when you need it, but copies are still acceptable.

   (This assumes that the `SudokuBoard` type has a copy constructor.)

   ```
     SubtreeExplorer(Threadpool& tp, SudokuBoard sudoku)
         : tp(tp), sudoku(std::move(sudoku)) {}
   ```
2. Pass an rvalue reference to the named variable by applying `std::move()`:

   ```
   SubokuBoard sudoku(filepath);
   tp.submit(make_shared<SubtreeExplorer>(tp, std::move(sudoku)));
   ```
3. Remove the named variable entirely and pass a temporary:

   ```
   tp.submit(make_shared<SubtreeExplorer>(tp, SudokuBoard{filepath}));
   ```

I'd suggest implementing option 1, but then *also* implementing either option 2 or 3 if you don't need to use the `sudoku` variable after this `make_shared` call -- otherwise you would be making a pointless copy.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I went with option number 1 and it worked like a charm.  Just a question, how do I know when an object will be copy-constructed or move-constructed?

Comment: I want the object to be always moved inside, and never duplicated.

Comment: @ninazzo If you always want it to be moved then you need to use an rvalue reference like you were before. Any time you don't move the value and try to copy it, you would get a compile-time error like you did here. In that case the solution would be to apply either option 2 or 3. Optionally, you can go with option 1 and also 2 or 3, and make the class `SudokuBoard` non-copyable -- though I wonder why one would need to enforce that.

Comment: I mean, in the use case I want to do now, I want it to always be moved. He said the first constructor allows the caller to either move-construct or copy-construct it. I'm new to C++. When am I copying it and when am I moving it?

Comment: @ninazzo You will not always know. Technically the default is copying (BUT compilers may internally optimize that to become a move when they know that does not change code behavior (like when the variable is discarded without further access)).
However when you have a parameter with && like here, this enforces moving. You also know it will be moved if you explicitly use std::move.
By the way, caring too much about this can quickly lead to infamous "premature optimization". Only pay much attention to ensure moving when you know your dataset is large.

Comment: @ninazzo Without knowing the implementation of `SudokuBoard`, we can't even say for sure that a move is different from a copy.